# Serial Port In C#

Tags: c#

I am working with a program the reads data from a file and plots it to a graph in real time. My stream is coming from a microcontroller output and I am building an interface to display the data. I am using stream reader in my routine, but I have a problem.

I have decided to use the data from the serial port directly. I get an error when I try to use the variable line that I have just read from the port. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
        int tickStart = 0;
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port;
        public string portname;
        public Parity parity;
        public int BaudRate;
        public StopBits stopbits;
        public int databits;
        int count;

        String line;

        public string PortName
        {
            get { return portname; }
            set { portname = value; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
        //graphing stuff    
            count = 0;
            portname = "COM1";
            parity = Parity.None;
            BaudRate = 9600;
            stopbits = StopBits.Two;
            databits = 8;
            port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(portname);
            port.Parity = parity;
            port.BaudRate = BaudRate;
            port.StopBits = stopbits;
            port.DataBits = databits;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            port.Open();
            count = 0;
            }


        void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
          try
            {
             line = port.ReadLine(); 
              count++;
              }
          catch (Exception ex)
             {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
         }



        private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            //graphing stuff
            if (list == null)
                return;

            // Time is measured in seconds
            double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;

            double value = double.Parse(line);
            list.Add(time, value);
           //graphing stuff

          }
```

Comment: double value = double.Parse(line); Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Try using double.TryParse() instead m

Comment: I also would like to know if there is a way to pause the timer if there is not data being recieved, i.e. to wait until data comes.. i tried using timer1.stop() but the stops the program completely

Answer (score 2):

in timer1_Tick, add an additional check for 'line == null', in addition to 'list == null'.

Assuming that your data comes in no more often than the firing rate of your timer, and, that the data received arrives all in one burst.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The data comes in one burst, but comes intermittently.

Comment: Then a better solution is, during the `DataReceived` event, is to post another event to your own code that says "this float has arrived".

Comment: It would be better to make your program data-driven, rather than depending on the timing of the arrival of events.  In your `DataReceivedEvent` handler, also do the `Float.TryParse(...)` operation (don't forget to use the Culture Invariant locale in case someone runs your program on foreign country configured operating systems), and then post the resulting float to your own code that adjusts the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what happens is that the timer ticks before a value has been read from the port for the first time. This means that `line == null` still, so you get the error.

The best solution would be to not start the timer before at least one line is read, but checking for `null` would also do the trick.

Comment: Yes. line ==null was causing the error! thanks. Is there any way to pause and go back into the timer1_Tick when I receive new data.. Because data is coming intermittently.. Just guide me in some direction, new to C#!

Comment: @Programming Enthusiast: The "correct" solution depends on what you want the graph to show during periods where no new data is coming in.

Comment: I just want it to stop which is why I have called timer1.Stop() to fix my original issue.   if (line == null)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                return;
            } But this is a one time fix and I need to restart the program in order to continue reading.

Comment: @Programming Enthusiast: Then you don't need a timer at all. Just do your processing immediately after `port.ReadLine()` returns.

Comment: @Prog - the timer has to go.  You can *never* make it work reliably with it.  You'll need to use Control.BeginInvoke() in the DataReceived event handler.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am working on that now.. I am not familiar with Control.BeginInvoke().. I was trying to run the routine that I currently have in timer1_tick into the port_DataReceived..